# Is the description meta tag important for SEO?

Tags: html, metadata

A surprisingly large number of websites does NOT have a `description` meta tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is a description of our website" />
```

Does this mean that the `description` meta tag is not important for SEO, or are the webmasters of those websites incompetent?

I asked this question to get help on the decision whether I should add a description meta tag to a website I am building.

Comment: I suppose it stopped being important for SEO when it began being [_abused_ for SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_stuffing), and when search engines simply became better at understanding whole pages.

Comment: This is a very good question!

Comment: "I asked this question to get help on the decision whether I should add a description meta tag to a website I am building." - This is out of scope for Superuser.  Questions around SEO or even search engines in general, are not on topic, here at Superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From moz.com:

> Meta description tags, while not important to search engine rankings,
> are extremely important in gaining user click-through from SERPs.
> These short paragraphs are a webmaster’s opportunity to advertise
> content to searchers and to let them know exactly whether the given
> page contains the information they're looking for.
>
> Google announced in September of 2009 that neither meta descriptions
> nor meta keywords factor into Google's ranking algorithms for web
> search. Google uses meta descriptions to return results when searchers
> use advanced search operators to match meta tag content, as well as to
> pull preview snippets on search result pages, but it's important to
> note that meta descriptions do not to influence Google's ranking
> algorithms for normal web search.

Source: https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description